# Printing event on C#

Tags: c#, printing

How can I keep track of Printer's activities such as:

- When did printing start?
- How many pages have been printed out? etc

Comment: Pages printed from your application, or pages printed from everywhere? Some details would be appreciated here.

Comment: can you post the source code of your print function?

Answer (score 2):

You would want to set up a service that listens to printer change notification events using the [FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162722%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [FindNextPrinterChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162722%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and [FindClosePrinterChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162721%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions. And listen to the PRINTER_CHANGE_JOB event. When a print job event is raised you can get access to the necessary job information from the [PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162854%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure.

This method should be taken with a grain of salt. I have found from experience that printer events are unreliable when the server is under load with many print jobs occurring at the same time. Some printer events will not fire.

Obviously this solution will take a whole lot of P-Invoking & Marshalling, so I wish you luck. If writing the application in C++ is an option it would probably be easier than in C# in this case.

Answer (score 1):

explaining it here is so boring.
I suggest you read the full article
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160129

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation).

Here is a blog-entry regarding getting printer-info using WMI: http://aleemkhan.wordpress.com/2005/09/20/getting-printer-information-through-wmi/

Here is some code on getting printer events (in VB.Net though): http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ITCG/thread/71258e18-5516-4a90-be76-5b83855b2841

Comment: and can be used as a class System.Printing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the Spooler API to get going? I've not used this before, but I recon it'll involve a fair amount of P/Invoke.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a7160b44-0984-48c4-afef-b9a6ee4a8483