# detect copy,paste,print system command using windows technologies?

Tags: c#, c++, com, vsto, excel-2007

is there a way out to detect copy,paste,print command using windows technologies? e.g if an excel application is running, and then user tries to print the sheet or copy the sheet, can we detect this kind of events? if yes, can someone tell me how it can be achieved? I need to do something once copy/paste command is initiated.

Comment: You may use [AddClipboardFormatListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649033(v=vs.85).aspx) to detect changes to the clipboard on Windows Vista and later. Earlier versions of Windows use [SetClipboardViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649052(v=vs.85).aspx). This does not address the need to detect printing though.

Comment: Thanks @William :) is there a way or workaround for printing?

Comment: Possibly through [FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162722(v=vs.85).aspx) and it's related functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different mechanisms for different events. For clipboard, you have to use Win32's Clipboard Chain. Read further [here](http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/monitor-clipboard-in-c/) and [here](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx).

Monitoring printer activity is also possible. There's an interesting [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160129) on MSDN as well as [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276269/printing-event-on-c-sharp) to similar questions on SO.